# After using query_posts the comment template is not being displayed (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

The following tells Wordpress to display all posts with category **Blog**,

The comment template is included at the bottom, but is not shown when the apge renders.

Any suggestions?

**home.php:**

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Blog
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */
 get_header(); ?>
 <div id="main-content">
  <?php query_posts('category_name=Blog&showposts=10'); ?>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
     <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php } else { ?>
     <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
     <?php the_content(); ?>
     <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
     <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyten' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
   </div><!-- #post-## -->
   <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
 </div><!-- #main-content -->
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to use `comments_template();` in a looping fashion -- it's only for single posts or page templates.

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template
Quote: "Description -- Loads the comment template. For use in single post and Page displays."

Answer (score 0):

If anybody wonders how, as seen here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-comments_template-outside-of-singlephp

```
<?php
$withcomments = 1;
comments_template(); ?>
```